# min undequeued buffer count exceeded camera2

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-camera2

I have an Android application that takes a photo without a preview surface. I have implemented this with the new camera2 for Lollipop - api 21

The code is like this:

```
                final CaptureRequest.Builder jpegRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
                // Render to our image reader:
                jpegRequest.addTarget(imageReaderSurface);
                // Configure auto-focus (AF) and auto-exposure (AE) modes:
                jpegRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                jpegRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, autoExposureModeFinal);
                jpegRequest.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, correctOrientation(context, characteristics));

                if (previews == 0) {
                    saveImage(camera, session, jpegRequest.build());
                } else {
                    // Take previews to dummySurface to allow camera to warm up before saving jpeg:
                    final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                    // Render to our dummy preview surface:
                    captureBuilder.addTarget(outputSurfaces.get(1));
                    // Configure auto-focus (AF) and auto-exposure (AE) modes:
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                    captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, autoExposureModeFinal);

                    session.setRepeatingRequest(captureBuilder.build(), new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                        int mNumCaptures;

                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession completedSession, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                            //Log.d("mNumCaptures", String.valueOf(mNumCaptures));
                            if (++mNumCaptures == previews) {
                                try {
                                    completedSession.stopRepeating();
                                    saveImage(camera, session, jpegRequest.build());
                                    //session.abortCaptures();
                                    closeCamera(camera, looper);
                                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                    error("Error saving image", e);
                                    closeCamera(camera, looper);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, null);

                }
```

I have tested this on a nexus 5x with Android 6 and it works. previews is set to 20 - you need to capture more images in order for the camera to adapt to the light.

I have tested this code with Galaxy s5 - Android 5 and it does not work.
I get this error: min undequeued buffer count exceeded

```
03-16 15:01:09.569: W/ArrayUtils(30646): Ignoring invalid value emboss
03-16 15:01:09.569: W/ArrayUtils(30646): Ignoring invalid value sketch
03-16 15:01:09.569: W/ArrayUtils(30646): Ignoring invalid value neon
03-16 15:01:09.599: I/CameraManager(30646): Using legacy camera HAL.
03-16 15:01:10.059: W/ArrayUtils(30646): Ignoring invalid value emboss
03-16 15:01:10.059: W/ArrayUtils(30646): Ignoring invalid value sketch
03-16 15:01:10.059: W/ArrayUtils(30646): Ignoring invalid value neon
03-16 15:01:10.089: W/ArrayUtils(30646): Ignoring invalid value emboss
03-16 15:01:10.089: W/ArrayUtils(30646): Ignoring invalid value sketch
03-16 15:01:10.089: W/ArrayUtils(30646): Ignoring invalid value neon
03-16 15:01:10.109: I/CameraDeviceState(30646): Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
03-16 15:01:10.109: I/RequestThread-0(30646): Configure outputs: 2 surfaces configured.
03-16 15:01:10.109: D/Camera(30646): app passed NULL surface
03-16 15:01:10.119: I/RequestThread-0(30646): configureOutputs - set take picture size to 800x480
03-16 15:01:10.209: I/CameraDeviceState(30646): Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
03-16 15:01:10.219: D/info(30646): Not using a front facing camera.
03-16 15:01:10.229: D/info(30646): Sensor orientation: 90 degrees
03-16 15:01:10.229: D/info(30646): Device orientation: 0 degrees
03-16 15:01:10.229: D/info(30646): Returning JPEG orientation of 90 degrees
03-16 15:01:10.229: I/RequestQueue(30646): Repeating capture request set.
03-16 15:01:10.239: W/LegacyRequestMapper(30646): convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
03-16 15:01:10.239: W/LegacyRequestMapper(30646): Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
03-16 15:01:10.239: W/LegacyRequestMapper(30646): Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
03-16 15:01:11.019: I/CameraDeviceState(30646): Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
03-16 15:01:11.209: E/BufferQueueProducer(30646): [unnamed-30646-2] dequeueBuffer: min undequeued buffer count (2) exceeded (dequeued=5 undequeued=1)
03-16 15:01:14.039: I/RequestQueue(30646): Repeating capture request cancelled.
03-16 15:01:14.439: E/BufferQueueProducer(30646): [unnamed-30646-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-16 15:01:14.439: E/BufferQueueProducer(30646): [unnamed-30646-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-16 15:01:14.439: E/BufferQueueProducer(30646): [unnamed-30646-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
03-16 15:01:14.439: E/BufferQueueProducer(30646): [unnamed-30646-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
```

I get the same error even if I set preview to 0.

I have found some topics about the error "min undequeued buffer count exceeded" but all of them are related to the deprecated camera class.
Do yo know if I could do something to fix this on Android 5?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As something to try, see if incrementing the maxImages argument to your JPEG ImageReader will help with this.